# How to move the clicked elemnet in the menu to scroll left?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/63/

I am using idangerous swiper to display the menu .

My requirement is to move the clicked item in the menu to scroll left .

please let me know how to do this

This is my code

```
var T1categories = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE" , "FOUR" , "FIVE", "SIX" , "SEVEN" , "EIGHT" ];
createhorizontaltab(T1categories);

function createhorizontaltab(categories) {
    var categoryArr = categories;
    var favoriteresultag = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < categoryArr.length; i++) {
        favoriteresultag += '<div class="swiper-slide"><span>' + categoryArr[i] + '</span></div>';
    }
    $("#swipecontainer").append(favoriteresultag).trigger("create");
}
$(document).on("click", ".swiper-slide", function() {
    $('.swiper-slide').removeClass('swiper-slide-active');
    $(this).addClass('swiper-slide-active');
});
```

Comment: Do you want an horizontal scroll in the menus?

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com Not horizontal scroll exactly , but when i clcik the elemnt in the menu it should move to the left (jsut 3 cm back).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/69/) and the part of the code updated:

```
$(document).on("click", ".swiper-slide", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.closest(".swiper-nav");
    var center = $parent.width()/2;
    $parent.css("margin-left", center);
    $parent.css("margin-left", 0);
    $('.swiper-slide').removeClass('swiper-slide-active');
    $this.addClass('swiper-slide-active');
    $parent.css("margin-left", center-$this.offset().left)
});
```

Comment: Thanks , it is moving to the left , but the other elemnts must also be visible . I just want to move to the just  left (spacing 3 cms )

Comment: @Kiran you want to move the clicked element 3cm to the left or to leave 3cm from the left?

Comment: exactly , it should dynamically align center so that the menu is entirely visible  .

Comment: its should be look like below link  (Second example Centered )http://darsa.in/sly/examples/horizontal.html

Comment: Thank you very much , but When i click on th last element (SIX) , why it is hiding  why it is hiding the first

Comment: Thank you very much , the width is not getting properly calculated and if i am reducing the screen size , then also there is a width problem in that case too .